AWS Cognito: Disable Sending Default Email
We are using AWS Cognito. We add users using the AdminCreateUser API and they receive the default invitation email. We want to disable sending this default invitation email and have our own mechanism in place.
As per the documentation, when using the AdminCreateUser API we can pass the MessageAction = SUPPRESS which do not send the default invitation email. But we have to set this flag in each API call. Is there a configuration on AWS console using which we can disable sending the default email, eliminating the need for explicitly setting this flag in each API call?
